# JPanel Image Background Overlapping Other JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, overlapping

I got two JPanels, one is an image an other a form. I'm trying to put the first panel with the background image behind other (painting) but it doesn't work

the panel background:

```
public JPanel fundo() {
    JPanel bg = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    try {
        Image backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/ceu.png"));
        setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return bg;
}
```

and this is the panel form (only to follow the logic):

```
public JPanel painelCadastro() {
    JPanel telaAtual = new JPanel();
    JTextField nome, telefone, aniversario, email;
    String definicao;
    JLabel lugarnome, lugartelefone, lugaraniversario, lugaremail;
    JTextArea endereço;

    telaAtual.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    //c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    //c.ipadx = 2;
    //c.ipady = 3;
    //c.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;  
    //c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;  

    lugarnome = new JLabel("Nome");
    c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridwidth = 1; //tamanho do compontente em celulas HORIZONTAL
    c.gridheight = 1; //tamanho do compontente em celulas VERTICAL
    c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na coluna
    c.gridy = 0; //localização da celula na linha
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
    telaAtual.add(lugarnome, c);

    nome = new JTextField("Digite seu nome aqui");
    definicao = "nome";
    c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridwidth = 7; //tamanho do compontente em celulas HORIZONTAL
    c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
    c.gridy = 0; //localização da celula na coluna
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    limpaCaixaTexto(nome, definicao);
    telaAtual.add(nome, c);

    lugartelefone = new JLabel("Telefone");
    c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na linha
    c.gridy = 1; //localização da celula na coluna
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    telaAtual.add(lugartelefone, c);

    telefone = new JTextField("Digite seu telefone aqui");
    definicao = "telefone";
    c.weightx = 2; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
    c.gridy = 1; //localização da celula na coluna
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    limpaCaixaTexto(telefone, definicao);
    telaAtual.add(telefone, c);

    lugaremail = new JLabel("Email");
    c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na linha
    c.gridy = 2; //localização da celula na coluna
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    telaAtual.add(lugaremail, c);

    email = new JTextField("Digite seu e-mail aqui");
    definicao = "e-mail";
    c.weightx = 2; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
    c.gridy = 2; //localização da celula na coluna
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    limpaCaixaTexto(email, definicao);
    telaAtual.add(email, c);

    //--------- INICIO CAMPO DATA -------------
    lugaraniversario = new JLabel("Data de Nascimento");
    c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na linha
    c.gridy = 3; //localização da celula na coluna
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    telaAtual.add(lugaraniversario, c);

    //JFormattedTextField dataAniversario = new JFormattedTextField(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM));
    //GregorianCalendar data = new GregorianCalendar();
    //dataAniversario.setText(data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (data.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + (data.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    JFormattedTextField dataAniversario = new JFormattedTextField(df);
    try {
        MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
        dateMask.install(dataAniversario);

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TelaPrincipalLocadora.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    definicao = "aniversario";
    c.weightx = 2; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
    c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
    c.gridy = 3; //localização da celula na coluna
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    limpaCaixaTexto(dataAniversario, definicao);
    telaAtual.add(dataAniversario, c);

    //--------- FIM CAMPO DATA -------------
    return telaAtual;
}
```

I'm calling him with this code:

```
private static void criarGUI() throws IOException {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vapstor Locadoras V1.0");
    frame.setSize(590, 456);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    TelaPrincipalLocadora demo = new TelaPrincipalLocadora();
    frame.setJMenuBar(demo.BarradeMenu());
    demo.painelCadastro().setVisible(false);

    frame.add(demo.painelCadastro()); //~HERE HE ADD

    frame.add(demo.fundo());
    System.out.println(demo.painelCadastro().isVisible()); // returns true

    demo.fundo().setOpaque(false); //HERE 
    frame.add(demo.fundo()); //AND HERE i guess is the problem

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I try other ways, and what i just get is the background image overlapping everything, even the painelCadastro() being visible..
Any ideas to give me a light?

*EDIT*

```
static class Background extends JComponent {

    Image backgroundImage;

    public Background() throws IOException {
        this.backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/ceu.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
        System.out.println("pintou o 7");
    }
}
```

on the main class:

```
    JPanel tela = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tela.add(new Background());
    tela.setOpaque(false);
    frame.setContentPane(tela);
    //frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    demo.painelCadastro().setOpaque(false);
    frame.add(demo.painelCadastro());
```

alright, i creat a secondary class, add the imagem from her to a panel, set the content to frame, but when i try to turn the form visible *still one or other*

**EDIT**
*it works, gracias*

but...
[*Where is the checkbox menuitens in this 'xp interface'?
Another question, is that a "label"? appears at the end of gui
I guess it just can be the Dimension wrong, because the frame is .pack*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpMIz.png)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I'd also be a good idea to call super.paintComponent

Comment: @MadProgrammer i edit it with a secondary class, but still doesn't work

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You code's kind of werid, you seem to be using `fundo` to create a background image for a `JFrame` (using `setContentPane`), but then you take it and add it to another frame in `criarGUI`?! But the component which is returned from `fundo` isn't actually the one which is used when setting the `contentPane`!??!

Comment: @AcauãPitta, don't forget to "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @MadProgrammer already done thanks! but i got a phantom label in the gui check out the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm trying to make heads and tails of your code...

First we have...

```
public JPanel fundo() {
    JPanel bg = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    try {
        Image backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/ceu.png"));
        setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return bg;
}
```

which on surface looks okay, but when we take a closer look at I notice that the panel which is been returned from the method IS NOT the panel which is been applied as the `contentPane`!?

But in your `criarGUI` you take the panel returned by the `fundo` method and add it to another frame ... but you're just adding a blank panel to the frame.

So for some reason you're taking content from the `demo` class and trying to add it to a different frame...why is a question that should really be answered, because that's kind of worrying...

Another problem is, you keep calling `painelCadastro`...

```
demo.painelCadastro().setOpaque(false);
frame.add(demo.painelCadastro());
```

but `painelCadastro` creates a new `JPanel` each time you call it, so changing its `opaque` state has no effect, as the second time you call it, you're getting a brand new instance of `JPanel`

The solution??  Either have your methods cache the result (AKA lazy loading) of their operations and always return the same instance of `JPanel` (which the initially created) or maintain a reference to the component which is returned.  Also, make sure you name your methods appropriately so they give more of an idea of what they do.  In your case `makePainelCadastro` or `createPainelCadastro` might be more appropriate

[image: Background]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testing();
    }

    public Testing() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setContentPane(new Background());
                    JPanel painelCadastro = painelCadastro();
                    painelCadastro.setOpaque(false);
                    frame.add(painelCadastro);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel painelCadastro() {
        JPanel telaAtual = new JPanel();
        JTextField nome, telefone, aniversario, email;
        String definicao;
        JLabel lugarnome, lugartelefone, lugaraniversario, lugaremail;
        JTextArea endereço;

        telaAtual.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        //c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        //c.ipadx = 2;
        //c.ipady = 3;
        //c.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;  
        //c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;  

        lugarnome = new JLabel("Nome");
        c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridwidth = 1; //tamanho do compontente em celulas HORIZONTAL
        c.gridheight = 1; //tamanho do compontente em celulas VERTICAL
        c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na coluna
        c.gridy = 0; //localização da celula na linha
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
        telaAtual.add(lugarnome, c);

        nome = new JTextField("Digite seu nome aqui");
        definicao = "nome";
        c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridwidth = 7; //tamanho do compontente em celulas HORIZONTAL
        c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
        c.gridy = 0; //localização da celula na coluna
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//      limpaCaixaTexto(nome, definicao);
        telaAtual.add(nome, c);

        lugartelefone = new JLabel("Telefone");
        c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na linha
        c.gridy = 1; //localização da celula na coluna
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        telaAtual.add(lugartelefone, c);

        telefone = new JTextField("Digite seu telefone aqui");
        definicao = "telefone";
        c.weightx = 2; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
        c.gridy = 1; //localização da celula na coluna
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//      limpaCaixaTexto(telefone, definicao);
        telaAtual.add(telefone, c);

        lugaremail = new JLabel("Email");
        c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na linha
        c.gridy = 2; //localização da celula na coluna
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        telaAtual.add(lugaremail, c);

        email = new JTextField("Digite seu e-mail aqui");
        definicao = "e-mail";
        c.weightx = 2; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
        c.gridy = 2; //localização da celula na coluna
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//      limpaCaixaTexto(email, definicao);
        telaAtual.add(email, c);

        //--------- INICIO CAMPO DATA -------------
        lugaraniversario = new JLabel("Data de Nascimento");
        c.weightx = 1; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridx = 0; //localização da celula na linha
        c.gridy = 3; //localização da celula na coluna
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        telaAtual.add(lugaraniversario, c);

        //JFormattedTextField dataAniversario = new JFormattedTextField(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM));
        //GregorianCalendar data = new GregorianCalendar();
        //dataAniversario.setText(data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (data.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + (data.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        JFormattedTextField dataAniversario = new JFormattedTextField(df);
        try {
            MaskFormatter dateMask = new MaskFormatter("##/##/####");
            dateMask.install(dataAniversario);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        definicao = "aniversario";
        c.weightx = 2; // percentual de tamanho em relação aos demais
        c.gridx = 1; //localização da celula na linha
        c.gridy = 3; //localização da celula na coluna
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
//      limpaCaixaTexto(dataAniversario, definicao);
        telaAtual.add(dataAniversario, c);

        //--------- FIM CAMPO DATA -------------
        return telaAtual;
    }

    public class Background extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage backgroundImage;

        public Background() throws IOException {
            this.backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return backgroundImage == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(), backgroundImage.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't add multiple components to the CENTER of the content pane. You need to have a parent / child relationship between the components.

The basic logic should be:

```
JPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(); // this is where you paint the image
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

JPanel child = new JPanel(); // this is the panel with your other components
child.setOpaque( false );

background.add( child );
frame.add( background );
```

Comment: @AcauãPitta, your code does NOT do what I suggested. Where did I use setContentPane() in my code??? What component did I add to the frame??? If you can't follow my example I don't know how I can help

Comment: @camickr The problem is the OP's code is creating a new `JPanel` each time they call there method `painelCadastro` and rather then maintaining a reference to the returned component, they are simply interacting with the different instance, `demo.painelCadastro().setOpaque(false);` and then `frame.add(demo.painelCadastro());` which obviously is just going to add an opaque component to the frame.  You hint at this, but the OP can't see teh forest for the trees :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  I know what the problem is, he is not following the simple structure I suggested. Of course if people keep writing the code for him then there is no reason for him to learn how to read a suggestion and simplify the problem.

Comment: @camickr Respectively, had you pointed out the referencing issue, the OP probably would have realised what they were doing wrong (and then understood what the code snippet was trying to suggest), but you just pointed out `BorderLayout`, which actually wasn't the "real" problem, but a compounding one, but at least the OP can't complain about the "code not work" as they now have a runnable example from which they experiment and compare with and which supports the statements I was making about the problems with their code :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  I believe, the main problem is the parent / child relationship of a Swing GUI. You can't keep adding components to the frame and expect them to display on top of one another. You need a structure of frame --> background --> panel. Your answer keeps referencing the frame via the setContentPane() and add() methods, which hides this relationship. The referencing problem is a secondary problem. Although I didn't comment on this I did highlight the structure for the proper code. Give  6 lines of code it should be easy to follow but the OP didn't attempt to follow the suggestion.

Comment: @camickr The one thing I think we can agree on is, the code is a mess, the OP is doing things (like repeatedly adding a new instance of the background) which make no sense :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for the answers, camickr i try make this relationship by creating a new class, but wont work guess what: because i dont know how... i want understand the logic, not the code. but i dont want a answer _"it's more or less something like this"_, i would like a answer like madprogrammer did, **"is this because this this and this"**.. anyways thank you.. btw what is OP? greetings from Brasil

Comment: `i try make this relationship by creating a new class` - the question was not about creating a new class, it was about adding a panel to an image. Whether you create a new class or just use `new JPanel()` is irrelevant, you need to add the panel to the background. `i want understand the logic` - that is exactly what my answer does. Its explains you need to use parent / child relationship for each component. The sample code shows how to do this is 6 lines of code. "OP" to me means "Original Poster".

Comment: `but i dont want a answer...` -  It is not about what you want. It is about what we think is needed to answer the question and the time we have. You are not the only person on the forum. This was a basic question that appeared to me that you did not understand the parent/child relationship. So I gave you the code to demonstrate the concept. You should easily have been able to follow the logic and change your code. I have given this same answer several times on the forum before with no problems. We are not here to write the code for you, only point you in the right direction.